# Skype Bot responding with empty body

Tags: node.js, skype, skype-bots

I'm trying to get a Skype bot up and running based off of the [echo example](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots/docs/tutorials/simple-nodejs) but I'm struggling to make a successful POST to my app. When I send a post to `/v1/chat` I get back a status of 201 (successful creation), and nothing in the body. My `console.log` does not print anything either, which leads me to believe that the `botService.on('personalMessage', ...)` function is not being run. Does anyone have any insight into how these POST requests should be formatted? I cannot seem to find anything in the documentation.

My code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const restify = require('restify');
const skype = require('skype-sdk');

const botService = new skype.BotService({
    messaging: {
        botId: '28:<bot’s id="ID176db9ab-e313-4d76-a60c-bc2a280e9825">',
        serverUrl : "https://apis.skype.com",
        requestTimeout : 15000,
        appId: process.env.APP_ID,
        appSecret: process.env.APP_SECRET
    }
});

botService.on('contactAdded', (bot, data) => {
    console.log('contact added');
    bot.reply('Hello ${data.fromDisplayName}!', true);
});

botService.on('personalMessage', (bot, data) => {
    console.log('message incoming');
    console.log(data);
    bot.reply('Hey ${data.from}. Thank you for your message: "${data.content}".', true);
});

const server = restify.createServer();
server.post('/v1/chat', skype.messagingHandler(botService));
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
server.listen(port);
console.log('Listening for incoming requests on port ' + port);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Final Edit & Solution**: I think the problem caused by Heroku somehow(it could be something with their free tier ,1 dyno). After some effort, I uploaded the program to Azure, and it is now working perfectly.

---

Potential Solution: You need to change the server address in the server.post command. If you run your program in "https:\www.yourwebsite.com/v1/chat" , you need to modify this;

```
server.post('/v1/chat', skype.messagingHandler(botService));
```

to this;

```
server.post('https:\\www.yourwebsite.com/v1/chat', skype.messagingHandler(botService));
```

Of course, don't forget to specify your app id, bot id, and app secret. If you don't have one, you need to generate a password in your Skype application page.

---

I have the exact problem with the OP. I followed the tutorial, and it doesn't specify how to modify our code to comply with our server. So, after running the program it only returns this;

{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"/ does not exist"}

In the Echo example in the Skype Bot Webpage; it says;

> "We'll assume the bot's URL for messaging was set to https://echobot.azurewebsites.net/v1/chat during registration."

Comment: It's possible that this could be an issue on Skype's end. I recently had 2 messages echoed by my bot, and then it stopped working once again. I'm deployed on Heroku by the way, but that should not make a difference given that the bot is just looking for api endpoints.

Comment: @polskais1 Mine is deployed to Heroku too. Just fyi

Comment: Hmm, good to know. I'll be sure to post a comment if I have any luck getting this thing working stably!

Comment: Any luck with getting your bot to work on Heroku? Seeing the same issues myself - testing locally with ngrok works fine. Switching the messaging webhook to Heroku results in the same as the OP. 

Via Papertrail, I see `skype-sdk.messagingHandler Received request, receiving data.` - but nothing from `console.log`

Tried the full URL in the server.post command, but no change. My last resort is trying Azure, but just curious if anyone's successfully deployed to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that [Procfile and worker processes are setup](http://shiffman.net/a2z/bot-heroku/).

[My bot](https://github.com/xameeramir/Bot-x-Skype) is working fine on [heroku itself](https://bot-x-skype.herokuapp.com)